# Youtube API - Difference between number of videos from channel statistics and number of videos uploaded

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-javascript-api

I am trying youtube API to get the number of videos using the call

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id=[id]&key=[key]

However, there is a mismatch in the number of uploaded videos. There are 178 videos uploaded in the channel and the channel statistics API is showing 177.

Why is the difference of 1 count?

**UPDATE**

After 3 days, I got the correct count from channel statistics API.

Still, the question is "Is there a chance to get the difference?"

If that is the case, I would prefer to use the number of videos uploaded instead of the channel statistics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Watch time report](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/1714329?ref_topic=1714326&guide=1714169) shows the following data collected from youtube.com, the video watch page, mobile Youtube apps (some data is only available from youtube.com).

> **Note**: Analytics views data is based in Pacific Standard Time, updated once a day, and has a delay of up to 72 hours. The numbers you
>   see in Analytics reports might be different from the numbers you see
>   on the video page, channel page, Video Manager, or other sources.

Then I suggest that you use the number of videos uploaded.